# Read only data slot from shapefile (R)?

Tags: r, geospatial, shapefile, rgdal

I have some very large shapefiles. I can read them into `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`'s using the `rgdal` function `readOGR`, but it takes a very long time for each file. I am actually only interested in the `data.frame` that shows up in the `@data` slot. Is there any way to read just the data, skipping the resource intensive polygons?

Example code:

```
## State of Alabama census blocks (152 MB compressed, 266 MB uncompressed)
shpurl <- "http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2011/TABBLOCK/tl_2011_01_tabblock.zip"
tmp    <- tempfile(fileext=".zip")
download.file(shpurl, destfile=tmp)
unzip(tmp, exdir=getwd())

## Read shapefile
nm  <- strsplit(basename(shpurl), "\\.")[[1]][1]
lyr <- readOGR(dsn=getwd(), layer=nm)

## Data I want
head(lyr@data)
```

Comment: Did you read thru the source code for `readOGR` ? It might well indicate either separate reads from the original file for different pieces of data, or that there is no such.

Comment: Taking a peek at the Wikipedia page -- if you can determine which of the actual files (.shp,.atx,.sbn, etc.) contain the `@data` you want, it may be easier to roll your own function to read directly from that file.

Comment: I would forget to do the obvious thing before asking. Yes, there is a separate call to create the `data.frame` for the `@data` slot.

Comment: fwiw, I'm pretty sure you could do this with OGR itself, but readOGR requires that you get the geometry as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shapefiles are compound files that store their attribute data in a file with extension `*.dbf`. (See the [Wikipedia shapefile article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) for a reference.) The `dbf` suffix refers to the [dBase file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbf), which can be read by the function `read.dbf()` in the `foreign` package.

So, try this:

```
library(foreign)
df <- read.dbf("tl_2011_01_tabblock.dbf")
## And, more generally, read.dbf("path/to/shapefile/shapefile-name.dbf")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( "/folder/file.dbf" ); 
DbaseFileReader dbfReader =  new DbaseFileReader(fis.getChannel(),false, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));

        while ( dbfReader.hasNext() )   {
          final Object[] fields = dbfReader.readEntry();

          Long field1 = (Long) fields[0];
          Long field2 = (Long) fields[1];
          System.out.println("DBF field "+i+" value is: " + fields[0]);
          System.out.println("DBF field 2 value is: " + field2);
        }
 dbfReader.close();
 fis.close();
```